# htaccess extension rewrite rule is working with Domain name but not working with IP showing error 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.txt$ $1.php
```

This is the rewrite rule I am using to a specific directory of my website
http:// xxx.yyy.zz.aa /~nishant/directory/.htaccess

to change all .php extension to .txt

when I look the directory file :
http: // www.mysite.com / directory/order.txt (it is working) but
http:// xxx.yyy.zz.aa / ~nishant/ directory/order.txt (is not working)

What do you suppose the problem is, and what is the proper solution?

Comment: Am I understanding correct, you you talking 2 different domain names on the same server, one works and another does not? It is most likely due to server configuration - you can't access the / ~nishant/ directory they way you are trying to. One would need to see your httpd.conf and/or .htaccess parts pertaining to this, in order to determine.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by your 'VirtualHost' - configuration: /etc/apache2/sites-available/...
In detail, look for 'AllowOverride ...' in a file containing 'VirtualHost xxx.yyy.zz.aa:80' or 'VirtualHost *:80'

There might be following statement missing:

```
<Directory /home/*>
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options
</Directory>
```

or:

```
<Directory /home/nishant>
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options
</Directory>
```

You need at least 'FileInfo' for mod_rewrite to work.
'Options' isn’t required for mod_rewrite but is commonly required if you are using .htaccess.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride